# Samsung galaxy z fold 4 - app automation help

Tags: applications, samsung, automation

Last night my wife was playing with the settings on her z fold 4, and she did some sort of app automation.

What do i mean?
She basically told her phone that whenever she opens certain apps, like WhatsApp, Messenger etc, to add a blue screen filter.

I have searched everywhere and i cannot find this setting to turn it off...

can anyone help please?

Comment: You may check the list of installed apps instead of settings. A blue screen filter can be provided by apps which always show a transparent overlay over all (or certain) apps. If the transparent overlay is colored with alpha transparency it can be used a blue light filter.

Comment: it was something in her settings, she showed me and asked what it meant I just cant remember what the setting was..